# MongoDB bulk data load on sharded cluster: any specific settings I can take advantage of?

Tags: mongodb

I have to insert @150 million records into a mongodb sharded cluster. The cluster comprises 5 3-member replica sets (primary, secondary, arbiter). Each record is uniform, about 1kb/record.

Given that I know the number and size of records, is there anything I should do with respect to shard configuration to optimize this data load? I'm thinking number/size of chunks, etc?